# How to discard lines with certain strings in list and output to new list

Tags: go

I have a list downloaded from a website in XML. I am trying to filter the list by discarding lines that contain a certain string and building the same type of list without the lines containing the string.
I have a `struct` type that's having another `struct`.
I'm trying to use `regexp` and `replaceall`, and failing at `replaceall`.

```golang
func (*Regexp) ReplaceAll
func (re *Regexp) ReplaceAll(src, repl []byte) []byte
```

There may be an entirely simpler way to filter a list to a new list that I'm missing somewhere, but I've found this as the closest possible solution so far. Please share other ways to grep and delete lines to a new list. The list is a byte at body and downloaded as a xml.

```golang
type PeopleList struct {
    Peoples []Person `xml:"peoples>person"`
}

type Person struct {
    ADD      string `xml:"add,attr"`
    Loc      string `xml:"loc,attr"`
    Har      string `xml:"har,attr"`
    Name     string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Country  string `xml:"country,attr"`
    Num       string `xml:"num,attr"`
    ADD2     string `xml:"add2,attr"`
    Distance float64

func fetchPeopleList(userinfo Userinfo) PeopleList {
    var p byte
    jam, err := http.Get(string(peoplelisturl))
    iferror (err)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jam.Body)
    peeps := body
    reg := regexp.MustCompile("(?m)[\r\n]+^.*BAD:.*$")
    rep := reg.ReplaceAll(peeps, p) // Here fails probably because of my syntax. Error: cannot use p (variable of type byte) as []byte value in argument to re.ReplaceAll

    fmt.Println(rep)
    iferror (err)
    defer jam.Body.Close()
```

Finally, I would like a new list in the same format as the first, only without the lines containing the string.

Comment: _"failing at replaceall"_ So explain the failure mode, and quote any errors received in full within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says you want to "discard lines", but `Replace`/`ReplaceAll`, as their names suggest, are for replacing matched patterns. Your regex is also a simple substring match, so the obvious solution would seem to be reading the file line by line and - as your title says - discarding lines containing the substring.

```
func fetchPeopleList(userinfo Userinfo) PeopleList {
    jam, err := http.Get(string(peoplelisturl))
    iferror (err)
    br := bufio.NewReader(jam.Body)
    defer jam.Body.Close()
    for {
        line,err := br.ReadString('\n')
        if !strings.Contains(line, "BAD:") {
            fmt.Println(line) // or whatever you want to do with non-discarded lines
        }
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Adrian. I will try this and share if it worked.

Comment: Checking and this doesn't work.
At: for line,err 
expected boolean or range expression, found assignment (missing parentheses around composite literal?)

Comment: Edited. Did you just copy, paste and run the code or do you actually understand it? Do you need further explanation?

Comment: Your added curly brace helped, and have been trying to incorporate into the larger code, still working on. TY!